# Differentiable $f|f|$ implies differentiable $f$ wherever $f$ vanishes

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, weak-derivatives

> Prove that if $f |f|$ differentiable in $a$ and $f(a)= 0$, then $f$ is differentiable in $a$.

The only thing i know is that
$|f´|(a) = 0$

I don´t know how to start with the demostration, i´ve tried appling the definition of derivative but don´t know how to continue.

Answer (score 4):

There's an example that does not work.

If $f(x)=|x|$, then $f(x)|f(x)| = x^2$ which is differentiable on $x=0$,
and $f(0)=0$.

But, $f(x)$ is not differentiable on $x=0$.